# Renaming SP2010 Service Application DBs

Tags: administration, database, service-application

Does anyone have any experience of renaming the SP2010 Service Application Databases. They were created and I don't recall an option to manually name them (as you can with Content DBs). They are in the format of:

Application_Registry_Service_DB_{32 Char GUID}

Which in itself isn't a problem, however we've discovered the MS DPM can't backup these databases due to the long name. All the Content DBs are sensibly named and I can see a way to unattach, rename and re-attach a Content DB. I'm just not sure how I can perfrom the same process with a service application DB.

Has anyone done this before and if so, how did you do this? (Powershell? If so, what cmds did you use?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename some service application databases using PowerShell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851878.aspx

Comment: Good find, much appreciated.